# Using ExpressionEngine and getting this error: A Database Error Occurred, Error Number: 1117, Too many columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, expressionengine

I’m building a site in ExpressionEngine where the client wants every image and text built into EE’s content management system as an editable field. Ok… Almost done. Currently have 1030 Channel Fields, across 20 Channel Field Groups, with in 20 Channels.

In trying to add Channel Field # 1031 and continue adding Channel Fields I get the following error:

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1117

Too many columns

```
ALTER TABLE `exp_channel_data` ADD `field_id_1036` text NULL
```

Filename: libraries/api/Api_channel_fields.php

Line Number: 675

I have spent the last 2 weeks creating these Channel Fields and I really don’t want to go back and restructure everything. So I’m wondering….

Is there a way to increase the number of columns to allow for the rest of the Channel Fields needed to complete this site? Or what ever needs to be done to allow me to add more channel fields?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank You

Comment: MySQL column limits are discussed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html Changing engines may effect them slightly, but there are not configuration parameters by and large.

Answer (score 1):

You’re hitting MySQLs limit. You can change the column types to more accurately reflect the type of data they contain, e.g. a column that stores a date or Boolean doesn’t need to be a `text` or `varchar` that is taking up unnecessary space in the table. There is also the [limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html) on how much data can be per row.

- Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. Storage engines may place additional constraints on this limit, reducing the effective maximum row size.

It may be time to better normalize the data.

Comment: I'm guessing he's using InnoDB and hitting the 1000 column limit based on the (partial) error message.

Comment: +1 for normalize the data.  Think about categories, think about related entries, think about grid/matrix.  For every field you create you are adding 2 additional columns to the _data table.